# Is there any way to check if some of the possible output lists are repeated?

Tags: list, prolog

For some code I'm having a huge number of possible output lists for L , but is there a way to check if any of these lists are duplicates?

Comment: And the snippets of the code you have tried so far??

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use Prolog' database, hashing your lists for efficiency:

```
:- dynamic generated_lists/2.

...
build_a_list(L),
term_hash(L, HashKey),
(  generated_lists(HashKey, Previous)
-> (  L == Previous
   -> writeln(duplicate(L)) % do something sensible
   ;  true % maybe duplicate hashing: assertz(generated_lists(HashKey, L))
   )
;  assertz(generated_lists(HashKey, L)) % unique so far
),
...
```

the check should be 'pushed' ASAP, to prune the evaluation time...

As an alternative, more efficient, you could use a [red black tree](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/nb_rbtrees.pl), but the feasibility depends if you can 'carry it' along the computation path.

Comment: 3x incorrect: 1 when the hash is suboptimal, or constant. 2 because leftover data from a previous run are reused. 3 because not re-entrant, nesting in `build_a_list/1`

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by huge number of possible output lists, so I will have to guess.

If you want to ensure that a particular goal (producing lists or whatever other terms) does have duplicate solutions:

Actually, this will succeed for all redundant solutions:

```
call_dups(Goal) :-
    bagof(t,Goal,[_,_|_]).

p([]).
p([a]).
p([b, c]).
p([a]).
p([c]).
p([]).


?- call_dups(p(L)).
   L = []
;  L = [a]
;  false.
```

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is what i was asking for was already predefined in prolog ... Where i should use bagof and setof and get the length of both output lists if similar then no duplicates

Comment: That's sounds like a terrible solution from a computational cost point-of-view as it seems to imply computing the lists twice. The ideal solution would be, of course, to prevent the generation of duplicated lists in the first place.

Comment: @PauloMoura: A factor of two is not much overhead compared to the inherent overheads when asserting entire goals instead of the necessary subterms.

Comment: Just a few years later to tell you it worked back then